# Storage of results in a matrix with a loop

Tags: r, loops

I have two nested For loops in which the inner loop feeds the calculation results into a matrix by

```
matrix[u,]
```

Hence, I get all results from the inner loop into the matrix and thats fine. However, I would like to keep each matrix generated from the inner loop in the k executions of the inner loop through the outer For Loop. However,

```
matrix[[k]][u,]
```

doesn't work (I initialised matrix= matrix()). But I do get the subscripts out of bounds error. Can somebody suggest alternatives?

Thanks

Edit
my code looks pseudo like

```
mat<-matrix()
for (k in a:b){
for (i in a:c){
function(parameter1)->q
c(q[1],q[2])->mat[i,]
}
mat[[k]]
}
```

Comment: Show us some more codes. with limited info, this may be what you are looking for. by using `[[]]` you are accessing list element, try `matrix<-vector(mode="list")`, and in loop `matrix[[k]]<-matrix()`, and by the way use variable name different from function

Comment: Hello, can I do this though I do need a matrix or entries and not a vector? Moreover, if I use the code with matrix<-vector(mode="list") I get the error *tmp*[[k]] subscript out of bounds (although I have nowehere a tmp varibale)

Comment: Tim, Can you add some example of you data structure?

Comment: Hey,....coudl you roughly describe what would help? The functions are self written and it would take very long to explain them. I added a small example

Comment: Do you want to obtain rows 1 to `k` of the matrix in the outer loop?

Comment: Hey..no it is about obtaining rows in the matrix from the inner loop (a:c) and then saving all the matrices which are generates like this in the a:b trials (the outer loop)

Answer (score 0):

Although, I still don't understand the question completely, this may be what you are looking.
Let me know, if this is not what you expected,

```
x<-matrix(nrow=10, ncol=10)
for (i in 1:10){
  for (j in 1:10){
    x[i,j]=i*j
  }
}
```

Comment: hey...i suppose your code adds the outler loop into the columns and the inner loop into the rows of the matrix? I just want that the inner loop with the calculation fills the matrix. This calculation is repeated k times (the outer loop) and gives rise to a new matrix each time. I want to save all these matrices.

Comment: so, outer loop populates the list of matrices, so, you want a list of matrix, and that is what I addressed in comment to your question.